# Sklearn linear regression model yields negative R2 value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I've been playing around with some fifa data and wanted to look at the relationship between dribbling and ball control. I've created a linear regression below, however when I use the `.score` method to obtain the R2 I get an output of -1.9345. This is obviously wrong as R2 can't be greater than 1. Could somebody explain in layman's terms where I've gone wrong.

Also, I've noticed when I do `metrics.r2_score(x_test,y_test))` I get the correct R2.

```py
x = fifa["Dribbling"].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = fifa["BallControl"].values.reshape(-1,1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
LinModel=LinearRegression()
LinModel.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(LinModel.intercept_)
print(LinModel.coef_)
y_estimates=LinModel.predict(x_test)

# Print R2 score
print(LinModel.score(x_test,y_test))
> -1.9345
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with R? R is a statistical programming language, it is not R2.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags. (removed)

Answer (score 2):

Sklearn's linear models sometimes yield unexpected behavior, especiallyif you're coming from a statistics background. From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) of `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, the `score` method returns the R^2 coefficient by default, which is in turn defined as follows:

> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 − *u*/*v*), where *u* is the residual sum of squares `((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum()` and *v* is the total sum of squares `((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum()`. The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

As you can see, if *u* is huge, then the R^2 coefficient will be negative. This is so because `sklearn` was made for predictive tasks, not inference, so some of its metrics do not follow textbook definitions.

For future reference, you do not need to reshape the target when declaring `y`. Sklearn's regression models can handle one-dimensional array-like structures.